# Simple PHP Form Not Submitting

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, innodb

the page does not seem to be writing to the database.  I have a feeling this may be a database error rather than the form submission itself.  There are no errors that I have found and I can't seem to figure out why the database isn't accepting my parameters.  Please see the code and the database structure below.  Please let me know if you need more information.

```
    <?php
session_name('shipshapeLogin');
session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
session_start();

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require('connect.php');
//require_once('business.php');

if(empty($_SESSION['id']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Ad Posting</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="advertise.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form action="" method="post" class="advertiseform">
<div>
<input class="field" type="text" name="business" id="business" disabled="disabled" placeholder="Business Name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>"  required="true" />
</div>
<div>
<input class="field" type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title" value="" size="23" required="true" />
</div>
<div>
<textarea input class="field" type="textarea" name="ad" id="ad" placeholder="Body" required="true">
</textarea>
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from" placeholder="Valid from:" required="true">
</div>
<div>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to" placeholder="To:" required="true">
</div>
<div>
<button type="button" id="clearbtn">Clear Advertisement</button>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Post Advertisement" class="submit" />
</div>
</form>
</div>

<?php


$business_name = $_POST['business'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$body = $_POST['ad'];
//$valid_date= $_POST['from']." to ". $_POST['to'];
$fromDate = $_POST['from'];
$toDate = $_POST['to'];


$query = "INSERT INTO Businesses_ads ( business_name, title, from, to, body, posted) VALUES ( :business_name, :title, :from, :to, :body, NOW())";


    $query_params = array(

        ':business_name' => $business_name,
        ':title' => $title,
        ':from' => $fromDate,
        ':to' => $toDate,
        ':body' => $body,
    );

        try{

        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex;
        }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: have you tested your connection to the database?

Comment: Why do you use multiple jQuery cores? You dont check if the POST-Request is set.

Comment: Yes, the connection works. I have checked each $_POST variable.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Q7UbqpFv You dont check POST-Vars. You only defined it as variable.

Comment: I checked them earlier.  They appear to be outputting the correct values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`to` and `from` are [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) which must be wrapped in backticks

Change:

```
( business_name, title, from, to, body, posted)
```

to:

```
( business_name, title, `from`, `to`, body, posted)
```

Comment: This didn't work, should I also backtick the values side of the query?  If not, could you provide the whole query?

Comment: No, you don't put backticks for your VALUES. @user2793987

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO Businesses_ads ( business_name, title, `from`, `to`, body, posted) VALUES ( :business_name, :title, :from, :to, :body, NOW())";   Did not seem to do anything.  Backticks are included.

Comment: Try what Adrian posted as a pastebin file, wrapping your PHP with `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {` @user2793987

Comment: I'm also suspecting this `value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>"` where this `$business_name = $_POST['business'];` should most likely be `$business_name = $_SESSION['username'];` @user2793987 something is contradicting itself. Or try removing `value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>"` altogether since you have it coming from a (POST) form and the session variable has not been assigned.

Comment: The only two `$_SESSION` related codes I see are `if(empty($_SESSION['id']))` and `$_SESSION['username']` so something is not matching (or set). Read my edited comment just above also. @user2793987

Comment: I don't know why that was the issue, but it was.  Thanks!!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. Sessions can get tricky at times and they do need to match. @user2793987 If one fails, the rest of the execution will follow also. Enjoy, cheers.